# Does this limit equal to 1 if $a_n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I was wondering if the limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k}{\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_k} = 1 $$ for all $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = 0$, because the term $a_{n+1}$ is close to 0 and so both sums are so close that their division reaches actually 1. If someone can answer me, I will be grateful! And, if is this statement true, can someone prove formally it?

Comment: I'm sorry if I have a bad english, because I'm brazilian and don't take much english classes.

Comment: Try to take the reciprocal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering if the limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k}{\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_k} = 1 $$ for all $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = 0$,

Define the sequence $~\langle b_n\rangle~$ such that
$~b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k.~$

If there exists some fixed $~\epsilon > 0,~$ and some fixed $~J \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that 
$\forall n \geq J, ~|b_n| > \epsilon,$

then the expression to be evaluated can be re-expressed as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}
1 - \frac{a_{n+1}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_k}. \tag1
$$

In (1) above, based on the "J" constraint, beyond a specific point, the absolute value of the denominator will never approach $~0,~$ while the numerator will approach $~0.~$

Therefore, if the "J" constraint is satisfied, then the limit is equal to $~1.$

---

For a counter-example, where the "J" constraint is violated, consider the sequence $~\langle a_n\rangle~$ defined by

- $~a_n = \dfrac{2}{n} ~: ~n ~$ even.
- $~a_n = -a_{n+1} ~: ~n ~$ odd.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If the series $\sum_k a_k$ converges to a nonzero number, use the [quotient law of limits](https://www.utrgv.edu/cstem/utrgv-calculus/limits/limit-laws/index.htm).

Comment: It is also easy to answer in case $\sum_k a_k = \infty$.  So the hard case may be: $\sum_k a_k = 0$.